# How to change the default paragraph Font in Wordpress theme with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I use the free theme "Benzer"in my wordpress blog. The parent theme is "Specia".

I'am trying to change the default paragraph font and make it better by placing this CSS code in the Special style.css file directly through Wordpress, but nothing changes...What's wrong please?

```
p {

font-family:Arial;
font-size:14
```

}

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important`?

Comment: No I didn't...I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

!Important are considerated a bad practice. Try to use the console to figre otu wich style is overwriting yours.
also, you miss the units in font size,

```
p {
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px
}
```

Should work better.

Comment: Of course it was 14 px..I forgot to write it in my post, but yes I put 14px right in my style.css..Still it doesn't work..

Comment: post the url, and I'll tell you what class to use.

Comment: www.siege-gamer.fr

Comment: your font size is determined in https://siege-gamer.fr/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/zyz6di6/2iqcx.css line 8973 (mind you, you have a cache plugin, so after change this in your wpfc plugin you should rebuild cache to see the changes)
Your font family is set in wp-custom-css, that means behind the customize button in the front, when you are logged as an admin.

Comment: By the way, www.siege-gamer.fr is broken, you can only access the https://siege-gamer.fr from outside France.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what's going on..I contacted my web hoster.My website is under surveillance...

Comment: Dear Christian: Pleasde give me more information about what you said 10 hours ago that my website is broken and not visible from outside France-> Country of access, the IP you used when testing, date and time of the test and error message). Thanks a lot

Comment: Of course: the browser shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I try to access www.siege-gamer.fr First, it takes me to http://www.siege-gamer.fr and then it sends me to https://www.siege-gamer.fr finally, it tried to redirect me to https://siege-gamer.fr  but  only displayed the error. If I access https://siege-gamer.fr directly, everything is Ok.